# JAAS with servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jaas

I am trying to use JAAS for my servlet application. I could get a basic JAAS simple authentication (non-servlet) working.

But with the servlet where to i set this variable?
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=test_jaas.config

I also tried exporting JVM_OPTS to this as per this page http://www.kopz.org/public/documents/tomcat/jaasintomcat.html

But I still keep getting, "No LoginModules configured" while creating LoginContex.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the servlet container. If you're using Tomcat you have to configure a JAAS realm. See the Tomcat configuration documentation under Realms.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Figure out this flags can be passed as an argument to startup.sh of tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

instead you can go to java_home/conf/security/java.security and add your config location by adding the following
`login.config.url.1=file:[test_jaas.config path]`